# how to change the algorithm environment?

Tags: algorithms

I am interested in changing the algorithm environment so that the numbered "Algorithm" title appears *at the bottom* instead of at the top, and also the three rulers (one above the Algorithm caption, second below the Algorithm caption, and third at the bottom of the whole environment) won't be there.

I couldn't find a way of doing it according to here:

http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/software/latex/doc/algodoc.pdf

Any ideas how to do that?

(Maybe I should define a new environment which is very similar to the Figure environment instead, only the heading is Algorithm instead of Figure?)

Comment: What package are you using to produce algorithms?

Comment: I am using the "algorithm" package with "algorithmic" inside the an algorithm environment for the actual algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `algorithm` accepts three options at loading time, in regards of the appearance of the algorithm: `ruled`, `boxed` and `plain`. The default is `ruled` but I think you are looking for the `plain` style.

Example in `plain` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FOR{$i=1 \to 10$}
    \STATE X
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{My algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Substituting `plain` with `boxed`:

[image]

And finally the default style (`ruled`):

[image]